# Incorporate INSERT Mysql query for MVC controller in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, oop, model-view-controller

So I've been stuck on this for quite a while, surprisingly the update and delete functions work just fine, however I cannot make the CREATE function work properly. Please have a look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
    <-------------- Entire model for admin panel-------------->>>>>>>> Connection to DB is working fine---------->>>>>>>>>>>

           <?php
    include_once "Model.php";

    class ModelPages extends Model {

        public function get($key) {

            $sql = "SELECT * from pages where page_key = '$key'";
            $row = '';

            $page = Null;

            foreach  ($this->pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                $page = $row;
            }

            // echo "<pre>";
            // var_dump($page);
            // exit;
            return $page;


        }


        public function getAll() {

            $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * from pages Where Id > 3");
            $result =  $statement->execute();
            $pages = array(); 
            if($result) {
                $pages = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
            return $pages;
        }  

        public function updatePage($params=array()) {
                if (!is_array($params)) {
                    return 'Params should be an array';
                }

                if (isset($params['table'])) {
                   $tableName = $params['table'];
                } else {
                   $tableName = 'pages';
                }

                $pageId = isset($params['page_key']) ? $params['page_key'] : null;
                $pageTitle = isset($params['page_title']) ? $params['page_title'] : null;
                $pageBody = isset($params['page_body']) ? $params['page_body'] : null;

                if ($pageId == null) {
                   return 'No page id provided'; 
                }

                $sql = "UPDATE " . $tableName . " SET 
                title = :title,  
                body = :body  
                WHERE page_key = :page_key";

            $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

            $statement->bindParam(':title', $pageTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
            $statement->bindParam(':body', $pageBody, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam(':page_key', $pageId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $result =  $statement->execute();

            return $result;
        }

        public function deletePage($pageId) {
            // build sql
            $sql = "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id = " . intval($pageId);

            $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $result = $statement->execute();
            return $result;
        }

        public function createPage($params=array()){
     if (!is_array($params)) {
            return 'Params should be an array';
        }

        if (isset($params['table'])) {
           $tableName = $params['table'];
        } else {
           $tableName = 'pages';
        }

        $page_key = isset($params['page_key']) ? $params['page_key'] : 'page_key';
        $pageTitle = isset($params['page_title']) ? $params['page_title'] : 'page_title';
        $pageBody = isset($params['page_body']) ? $params['page_body'] : 'page_body';



            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tablename ." SET page_key=:page_key, title=:title, body=:body ";

            // prepare query for execution
            $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

            // bind the parameters
            $statement->bindParam(':page_key', $_POST['page_key']);
            $statement->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
            $statement->bindParam(':body', $_POST['body']);

            // specify when this record was inserted to the database


            // Execute the query
            $result = $statement->execute();
            return $result;
        }
    }



<?php

include 'controllers/controller.php';
include 'models/Model.php';
include 'models/ModelPages.php';


<------------------------ADMIN CONTROller----------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>


class Admin extends Controller {
    function __construct() {

        // create an instance of ModelPages
        $ModelPages = new ModelPages();

        if(isset($_POST['page_key'])) {
            // TODO: update DB
             $tableData['page_body'] = $_POST['body'];
             $tableData['table'] = 'pages';
             $tableData['page_title'] = $_POST['title'];
             $tableData['page_key'] = $_POST['page_key'];


             $response = $ModelPages->updatePage($tableData);

            if ($response == TRUE) {
               header("http://188.166.96.184/workspace/marem/AAAAA/index.php?page=admin&success=true"); 
            }

        }

        if(isset($_GET['page_key'])) {
            // by default we assume that the key_page exists in db
            $error = false;
            $page = $ModelPages->get($_REQUEST['page_key']); 

            // if page key does not exist set error to true
            if($page === null) {
                $error = true;        
            }

            // prepare data for the template
            $data = $page;
            $data["error"] = $error;

            // display
            echo $this->render2(array(), 'header.php');     
            echo $this->render2(array(), 'navbar_admin.php');
            echo $this->render2($data, 'admin_update_page.php');
            echo $this->render2(array(), 'footer.php');

        } else {
            // case: delete_page
            if(isset($_GET['delete_page'])) {
                $response = $ModelPages->deletePage($_GET['delete_page']);
                if($response == TRUE) {
               header("http://188.166.96.184/workspace/marem/AAAAA/index.php?page=admin&deleted=true"); 
             }

         }
        }

        //Get table name and make connection
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $page_key = $_POST['page_key'];
        $page_title = $_POST['title'];
        $page_body = $_POST['body'];

         $response = $ModelPages->createPage();


    if($response=TRUE){
 header("http://188.166.96.184/workspace/marem/AAAAA/index.php?page=admin&created=true");

}



    }
}


        // load all pages from DB
        $pages = $ModelPages -> getAll();

        // display
        echo $this->render2(array(), 'header_admin.php');     
        echo $this->render2(array(), 'navbar_admin.php');     
        echo $this->render2(array("pages"=> $pages), 'admin_view.php');
        echo $this->render2(array(), 'footer.php');    


}

}
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any error? in this sentence `$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tablename ." SET page_key=:page_key, title=:title, body=:body, ";` there is an extra `,` comma after `:body`.

Comment: `INSERT INTO " . $tablename`  variable **$tablename** is not defined

Comment: in controller part `$statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);`  how can you call `pdo` property of the model using `$this`? it doesn't exist for the controller class

Comment: I have not been getting any errors, but thanks for that anyway. it does exist, here is the controller for the admin

Comment: Where can i send it to you ? Should  I just post the whole thing here ?

Comment: that function is just a part of the admin controller that handles the READ , UPDATE and DELETE  , and they all work great, I just can't seem to get a working function for the insert part

Comment: so which one doesn't work? model or controller? if controller - remove model from your question it is useless. if model remove controller then. and post whole class with all functions, methods and properties.

Comment: here you go alex , I've put everything there for you to see, I would be very gratefull if you could help out

Comment: so why do you want to save `NULL`s?  here: `if(!isset($_POST['page_key'])) { ... $tableData['page_key'] = $_POST['page_key']; ...` is it really what you are trying to get work?

Comment: That was a mistake , I've been going out of my mind with this for the last couple of day , and today I just tried to make it as similar to the update one as possible since that is working just fine:P

Comment: so? what is your problem or issue now?

Comment: It does not insert any values into the database

Comment: My guess is that it is something wrong with the function in the controller, but I do not have any errors for it ,any notices or warnings at all

Comment: there is no guess. there is NO VALUES you are trying to insert only `page_key=NULL` nothing else!

Comment: I've removed that part already , still nothing :P

Comment: blah, blah, blah... show me the code not the comments :-)

Comment: what more code do you need ?

Comment: the code that is not working!  you posted first variant of the code, when I made my comments you've replaced it with new one. now you've told *I've removed that part already* So how should I know what do you debug now?

Comment: done, sorry about the misunderstanding , I thought you might need code from the database connection or smth

Comment: hey, do you read what I wrote? you changed code in the model. but your problem is in controller! you send filtered NULLs from there!

Comment: but the nulls were in the model

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. I always start from the beginning. If you send nulls, why should I read the rest? fix the controller first - will talk about the rest then

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about either , If I weren't confused myself or if I could have managed to do everything I would not have posted this here

Comment: I know the problem is within the controller , I have been saying that all along

Comment: blah, blah, blah... again :-) fix the code! post updated! Didn't you find these lines:  
`if(!isset($_POST['page_key'])) { ... $tableData['page_key'] = $_POST['page_key']; ...` in your controller?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $page_key = $_POST['page_key'];
        $page_title = $_POST['title'];
        $page_body = $_POST['body'];

         $response = $ModelPages->createPage();

Comment: did you read my answer? look. now you changed it to `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` but since you already have `if(isset($_POST['page_key'])) {` in UPDATE flow so you **NEVER** reach your `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` condition when you want to call `createPage` downthere. Do you understand the problem?  when you do `if` by meaning `switch ...case... case..` you should use the SAME variable to detect the current mode (controller action).

Comment: so what if I made a separate controller for the create part ? wouldn't that be easier ?

Comment: did you read my answer? show me your html form. you should just add there `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="create">` when you want to call create action and `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">` when update

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `if(isset($_POST['page_key'])` on the top:

```
class Admin extends Controller {
    function __construct() {
        // create an instance of ModelPages
        $ModelPages = new ModelPages();
        if(isset($_POST['page_key'])) {
           ...
           if ($response == TRUE) {
           header("http://188.166.96.184/workspace/marem/AAAAA/index.php?
        }
```

and it is used to call `$response = $ModelPages->updatePage($tableData);`

your code never reach the part with good values at the bottom:

```
 if(!isset($_POST['page_key'])) {
    ...
    $response = $ModelPages->createPage($tableData);
```

So my simple but not the best suggestion is use extra parameter when `POST` like `action`. so you can check:

```
 if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='update') {
    ...
 } elseif (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='create') {
    ...
 } etc...
```

hope this will help you for now :-)

Answer (score 0):

> $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tablename ." SET page_key=:page_key, title=:title, body=:body ";

$tablename is not in scope when the statement above is executed. And you've got no error handling in the code.